# How do we get the current logged in user in a custom button

Tags: custom-button

Is there a way i can get a currently logged in user in a custom button running on javascript?

I have custom button on where i am trying to update certain fields like activated by. Is there a way i can get in a currently logged in user in the javascript?

Thanks

UPDATE :

Code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")}

var retVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
if(retVal)
{
var OrderObj = new sforce.SObject("Order__c");
OrderObj.id = '{! Order__c.Id}'; /* Need Id field to update Order*/
OrderObj.Status__c = 'Activated'; /* Change status */
OrderObj.Activated_By__c= {!User.Id};


/* update method takes an array of Orders; init to 1 element - 'OrderObj' */
var result = sforce.connection.update([OrderObj ]);

if (result[0].success == 'false') {
alert(result[0].errors.message);
}
else {
location.reload(true); /* redisplay the detail page */
}
}
```

Here is the error

[image]

Comment: Here is a good example - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AbWTIA0

Comment: Thanks @kurunve. It was exactly what i was looking for. If you can add it as answer i can accept it and could be helpful for others who might be looking for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a global [`User`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm) object:

```
<a href="/{!$User.Id}">{!$User.Alias}</a>
```

In a custom button set the Behavior to "OnClick JavaScript", add following javascript `location.href = "/{!$User.Id}"` and add the button to the page layout:

[image]

Comment: No idea how to use it in Custom Javascript button

Comment: @kurunve Check my update

Comment: @SergeyUtko i tried using the global User variable in the custom button, but it was throwing an error "Illegal" I couldnt make anything out of that error

Comment: @Prady strange... Works well for me.

Comment: @Prady, could you post your code? That example works for me as well

Comment: @kurunve sergeyUtko I have updated my code on the Question.

Comment: @Prady just do OrderObj.Activated_By__c= "{!User.Id};" to ensure that those assigned variable is string